# Excel: create a Top 10 list formulaically

Tags: excel, excel-2013

TL;DR

- I'm looking for a formula-driven way of generating a Top 10 list based on a user-selected filter
- The underlying data contains multiple instances of how the Top 10 list will be aggregated, i.e. a Top 10 list of vendors, where the underlying data contains multiple transactions per vendor

More detail:

I'm creating a financial dashboard by department manager with various financial metrics. I'm looking for guidance on building a 'Top 10' list within this dashboard that automatically updates based on the selection of a budget manager from an existing drop-down list.

One such 'Top 10' list will be a list of top vendors used.

I've tried a combination of LARGE(), RANK(), INDEX(), and MATCH() formulas, but I haven't been able to get them to work, mostly because of the structure of my underlying data.

The data I am using to drive the dashboard contains transaction level data for the entire company, i.e. for any given vendor, there are multiple transactions that span departments and even within departments the same vendor will have multiple transactions (sometimes hundreds or thousands). I need to sum all activity by vendor and then rank the top 10 vendors by transaction volume for each department manager. In addition, the other sections of my dashboard have the ability to show all of a manager's departments, or any single department under his/her management (I have two drop-down lists to control the views). I would like to retain this ability in the 'Top 10' section, but it's not a deal-breaker.

For my specific purpose, I can't really use a PivotTable or Data Table and/or manually change filters. It doesn't elegantly match the dashboard, but more importantly the 'Top 10' feature of PivotTables brings in 'Blank' vendors which almost always skews the top 10 list. I don't want to have to do translations of my data or introduce manual workarounds or maintain a separate list of all vendors that I need to manually update each month.

I've seem some wizardry on these boards, so hopefully someone can help me with my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You say you don't want a separate list of vendors, but is an extra hidden sheet amenable to you? The way I see it, this can be done really quickly by a Pivot Table in a hidden sheet, then just use the `GETPIVOTDATA` formula to extract them, adding a condition to leave out the blanks. Have you tested this as well?

Comment: can you add a sample data plus a sample desired result. sorry, i get dizzy easily in long paragraphs. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your data has a column header in A1 and data in A2:A15 then stick =A1 in C1 and enter the formula below into C2 as an array formula (instead of pressing enter press control-shift-enter).  C2 then gives the most frequent value in A2:A15.  Then copy C2 to C3, C4 and so on down to C11 to get the next most frequent successive values.  If your data extends beyond A15 you will need to change the forumula by replacing A$1:A$15 with a range that contains your data.  If you want the top ten list in a different column from C1:C11 you will need to replace C$1:C1 with wherever the header for the top ten list will be.

The formula for C2:

=IF(COUNT(MODE(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$1:A$15)=0,MATCH(A$1:A$15,A$1:A$15,0)))),INDEX(A$1:A$15,MODE(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$1:A$15)=0,MATCH(A$1:A$15,A$1:A$15,0)))),VLOOKUP("?*",IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$1:A$15)=0,A$1:A$15,""),1,0))

Note: I didn't come up with this horrible thing.  It came from http://excelusergroup.org/forums/t/201.aspx so you can follow its derivation there if you want to see how it came about.